# how to avoid the currency symbol in the value

Tags: jquery

i am trying to get the comma separated values ..

```
var colData = 4234;
var options = { style: "currency", currency: "INR" };
colData = colData.toLocaleString('hi-IN', options);
```

this is jquery code..

i am expecting the output as " 4,234.00  "

but the actual output was " Rs.4,234.00 "

i have tried by removing the options line

```
var colData = 4234;
colData = colData.toLocaleString('hi-IN');
```

but the output was " 4,234  "

and i have tried in replacing "hi-IN" with "en-IN " but had the same above result..
please help me.. thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to include a currency code, use style `decimal` and set `minimumFractionDigits: 2`.

**Demo:**

```js
alert(4234..toLocaleString('hi-IN', { style: 'decimal', minimumFractionDigits: 2 }));
```

Comment: Wow... What's the significance of `..`?

Comment: Did I rollback or you rolled back?

Comment: @David Hedlund i don't know why " alert(4234..toLocalString)"    you mentioned  ..

Comment: anyways i have got my answer with small correction in my code.. thank you...@David Hedlund

Comment: Well the `..toLocaleString` was just a hack to get around the fact that `.toLocaleString` is not accessible on the number primitive. `(4234).toLocaleString()` would've had the same effect. Introducing a variable, as in the question, is the way to go, I just wanted a oneliner for my answer :) `minimumFractionDigits` was the relevant part of the answer.

Comment: @PraveenKumar: I rolled it back because `4234.toLocaleString()` throws an exception.